# Unable to edit Asp.net DropDownList from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm working on an ASP.net Web Forms application (not MVC) and I have a **DropDownList** wrapped by a **TemplateField** in a **DetailsView** like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate> </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate> </EditItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="myStatus" runat="server" DataSourceID="DBStatus" 
                              DataTextField="DESC" DataValueField="CODE"
                              Enabled="false" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Status") %>'>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

as you can see at insertion its not enabled **(Enabled="false")**

for simplicity I wanted to use the insertion **items/fields** to achieve a **search**
so I want to enable my **DropDownList** for that **search**

I tried using these from code-behind on **DetailsView_PreRender and Page_Load** but nothing worked:

```
DropDownList Status = DetailsView1.FindControl("myStatus") as DropDownList;
Status.Enabled = true;
```

and i also tried

```
Status.Attributes.Add("enabled", "enabled");
```

i also debugged it, and these commands are executed but the DropDownList doesn't want to be enabled.
any thoughts ?

thanks.

Comment: When you used it in Page_Load, did you call it inside  **if(!IsPostback)**?

Comment: Do you have rows in your DetailsView?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by rows, sorry. All i have in my detailsview are labels, textboxes and dropdownlists and each of them is within a TemplateField.

Comment: If you look at the example on this page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.insertitemtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx it seems you have to use **DetailsView1.Rows[x].FindControl("myStatus")** where x is the index of the ddl in the dv.

Comment: Thank you Plue, But unfortunately that code has the same effect as DetailsView1.FindControl("myStatus")

Comment: I found a solution but I don't like it, I added a hidden button that enable the ddl using the FindControl method and clicked it automatically when the page opens using javascript ... but its too much , there should be something easier